# Windows command to list the windows application event log

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

Can anyone please tell me the windows command to list the windows application event log on a server.

I have the powershell command, but for the servers did not install powershell I need the windows command to pull the event log. Thanks,

Answer (score 4):

[Wevtutil](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732848.aspx)

> Applies To: Windows 8, Windows Server 2008, Windows Server 2008 R2,
>   Windows Server 2012.
>  Enables you to retrieve information about
>   event logs and publishers. You can also use this command to install
>   and uninstall event manifests, to run queries, and to export, archive,
>   and clear logs.

Example (from `wevtutil qe /?`)

```
wevtutil qe Application /c:3 /rd:true /f:text
```

or (more complex):

```
wevtutil qe /rd Application /q:"*[System[Provider[@Name='Microsoft-Windows-Perflib'] and (EventID=1023)]]" /uni:false /f:text
```

With the `/r` switch runs the command on a remote computer.